# iOS 5 MapKit, MKPlacemark, running iOS 4.3 app on iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, mapkit, core-location

I have the problem that I'm trying to run an app developed on the iOS 4.3 SDK on the iOS 5.0 SDK simulator.

I'm using the `MapKit` framework and here is my problem:

I'm getting an error message that the MapKit framework cannot find the header `<CoreLocation/CLPlacemark.h>`.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Have you added the CoreLocation framework to your project?

Comment: Yes, but I`m still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
#import <CoreLocation/CLPlacemark.h>
```

with

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the application hasn't included the `CoreLocation` framework.

You must import this by doing:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

Also do not forget to add this framework to your target in the project settings in:

Project > *YOUR TARGET* > Build Phases > Link binary With Libraries.